# router function not triggering

Tags: backbone.js, backbone-routing

In my backbone function, i am navigating a id to routers, but the function not calling... as well i have given the different sample navigate urls to my links, those are not calling the functions..

mycode :

```
    (function($){

        var myRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({
            routes:{
                "":"defaultRoute", //onload it works
                '#/name/:id':"nameData", 
                             // i am calling this function on default Router
                '#/project/:id':"projectData"
            },
            defaultRoute:function(){
                console.log('default')
                startRoute.navigate("#/name/3"); // i am redirecting
            },
            nameData:function(id){
                console.log(id); // id not consoling not called this func.
            },
            projectData:function(project){
                console.log(project);
            }
        });


    var startRoute = new myRouter();
    Backbone.history.start();
    })(jQuery);
```

my url : `http://localhost:85/router/web/#/name/3`

my html :

```
<ul class="name">
                <li><a href="#/name/1">name1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#/name/2">name2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#/name/3">name3</a></li>
                <li><a href="#/name/4">name4</a></li>
                <li><a href="#/name/5">name5</a></li>
            </ul>
```

any one find me the wrong this what i do here.. please

Comment: Did you look at the [documentation](http://backbonejs.org/#Router)? Your routes don't look right.

Comment: may be i wrongly understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All my functions are correct, by mistrake i added the hash on the routes prams.

update function here:

```
(function($){

    var myRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({
        routes:{
            "":"defaultRoute",
            'name/:id':"nameData",
            'product/:id':"projectData"
        },
        defaultRoute:function(){
            console.log('i am default');
        },
        nameData:function(e,id){
            console.log(id);
        },
        projectData:function(project){
            console.log(project);
        }
    });

var startRoute = new myRouter();
Backbone.history.start();
})(jQuery);
```